# Python, how trace operations over functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my project i would trace some operations achieved on my functions (like call number ecc ecc)
Which is the best solution for do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify. This is pretty vague as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is using decorators.
The following
defines and applies a function decorator that counts the number of calls made to the decorated function and prints a trace message for each call:

```
class tracer:
 def __init__(self, func): # On @ decoration: save original func
  self.calls = 0
  self.func = func
 def __call__(self, *args): # On later calls: run original func
  self.calls += 1
  print('call %s to %s' % (self.calls, self.func.__name__))
  self.func(*args)



@tracer
def spam(a, b, c): # spam = tracer(spam)
 print(a + b + c) # Wraps spam in a decorator object
```

Notice how each function decorated with this class will create a new instance, with its own saved function object and calls counter. Also observe how the *args argument syntax is used to pack and unpack arbitrarily many passed-in arguments. This generality enables this decorator to be used to wrap any function with any number of positional arguments; this version doesn’t yet work on keyword arguments or class-level methods, and doesn’t return results but works for general concept.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trace functionality built into python. For example:

```
python -m trace -t your_program.py
```

this will list all functions as they are called

```
python -m trace -l paths.py
```

This will show a summary of all functions that were called

more information here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use a Python magic: decorator, e.g., if you want to count the execution time of a function, you can define a decoration like this:

```
# This is in Python 3
ex_time = 0
def dec(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global ex_time
        ex_time += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@dec
def your_func(a):
    # Define your function here
    print(a) # For example

# Let's test
your_func('hello')
your_func('world')
print(ex_time)
```

Check if the result is 2.